# How do I mount a ceiling fan to this fan box?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I want to put up some ceiling fans in my house. There are already some fan boxes in the ceiling that were covered with blanking plates (if there were fans there before, I assume the previous owners took them when they moved).

[image]

It looks like this kind of box would have originally come with some screws, which I don't have:

http://www.alliedmoulded.com/media/686348/9373-FR.jpg

Here is a drawing where the embossed text can be seen more easily. http://www.alliedmoulded.com/media/941565/9373-FR.pdf

So my questions are:

1. Is this box intended to have the fan supported with screws going through the two notches in the sides, so that the fan is supported by the joist behind it instead of by the box itself?
2. The text on the box says "Use #12-14 x 1-1/2 long screws". Can I just buy [these screws](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-12-x-1-1-2-in-Slotted-Zinc-Plated-Steel-Hex-Head-Sheet-Metal-Screw-4-Piece-per-Pack-813141/204275292) and use them to mount a ceiling fan to this box? Or would there have been anything special about the original screws?

Comment: There is nothing special about the screws.  The box however is designed to make it so those screws drive directly into the ceiling joist, note how the wiring compartment straddles the joist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both of your questions.

The screws go into the notches/holes at the 9 and 3 o'clock positions in the photo of your box.

The two center holes are just to mount the box itself until a fan is installed.